# Does parallel vector field only refers to tangential vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry

From the book,

> Vector field along a curve $\alpha(t)$ on surface $M$ is **parallel** along $\alpha$ if tangential component of $\nabla_{\alpha'}^{\mathbb{R^3}}V$  ($=\frac d {dt}V$) is zero.

This seems fine until I saw the property that parallel vector field must have constant norm. Isn't this true only when $V$ is tangential to $M$? Has the book missed this information in the definition?

Comment: Jason, if you check carefully, when your text defines a vector field on a surface, it specifies (or it sure should!) that it be everywhere tangent to the surface.

Comment: I thought it means the curve is on the surface only...

Comment: You said "the book" twice and gave its title/author $0$ times. Hence, nobody can check if the definition there is missing something or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ted Shifrin said, the vector field under consideration "lives" on the surface: for every point $p$ where it is defined, $V(p)$ belongs to the tangent plane $T_pM$. Although "the book" may have introduced surfaces as objects in $\mathbb R^3$, the geometric notions considered here are intrinsic to the surface: it's best to think of them from the viewpoint of a Flatland (SurfaceLand?) inhabitant.